# How to order your troops to guard a particular place?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings, age-of-empires-ii-hd

I started playing Age of Empires 2 in 2008 but as I remember, there was an option to make your troops stand at a particular place and guard. Yesterday I downloaded it again (Age of Empires 2 HD version) but there ain't any option for that. Why?

Comment: I think you'll have to enable the advanced menu (gear icon above the map).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to **turn on advance commands** -> Top right corner of the minimap.